# Error para registrar una APP en Google Play

Tags: java, android, google-play

Saludos amigos tengo un problema estoy tratando de registrar una APP que hice que es um botón de pánico. Cuando presionan el botón la APP manda un SMS a mi servidor y del servidor envio Emails y SMSs a los contactos configurados en la plataforma web.

Sin embargo estoy tratando de subirla al Play Store y me asignan este error.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te está señalando que elimines el permiso que especifica del manifest.

Comment: Si eso lo se, lo que no se es si las políticas actuales de Google Play restringen el uso de SMS y de sus permisos en aplicaciones, porque he tratado de hacer varias cosas especificar en las políticas de privacidad de la APP para que me acepten la APP pero nada.

O no se si simplemente ahora no registran aplicaciones que usen el envío de SMS.